# Bash script: Appending text at the last character of specific line of a file

Tags: linux, bash, append

I am trying to append a variable at the last character of a specific line of a file from a bash script.

The file is called `myfile.txt` and what I want to do is to append the contents of a variable named `VERSION` right after the last character of the line of the file that contains the unique string `MYVERSION`.

That is, if in this line there is the following:

```
MYVERSION=0.1
```

and `VERSION="-custom_P1"` then, I want to have the following:

```
MYVERSION=0.1-custom_P1
```

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: What I also want to do is to be able to restore the initial value of `"MYVERSION"`. I managed to store it in a variable called `"OLD_MY_VERSION"` but when I am trying to restore with `sed -i "/^MYVERSION=/ c\$$OLD_MY_VERSION myfile.txt` I am getting `"$MYVERSION=0.1"` instead of `"MYVERSION=0.1"` (without the quotes of course). Any idea on how to remove the extra character ($)? If I don't put the extra $, I am not getting the contents of the `"OLD_MY_VERSION"` variable in the replacement but just `"$OLD_MY_VERSION"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -i "/^MYVERSION=/ s/\$/$VERSION/" myfile.txt
```

The idea is that it finds a line that starts with MYVERSION= and then replaces the end of that line with the contents of the $VERSION environment variable.

Edit: originally I wasn't sure if the first `$` needed to be escaped, but @sehe's comment and its upvoters convinced me that it does.

Comment: Ohh..of course in the end of the sed command that you typed it goes the filename (i.e. myfile.txt) just in case someone is wondering!

Comment: @limp: thank you for pointing that out, I added `myfile.txt` to the end of the command.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sed -e "s/^MYVERSION=/MYVERSION=.*$/&${VERSION}/g" < myfile.txt
```

The command appends the value of VERSION to the line with 'MYVERSION='

Comment: I think you misread the question: VERSION is already a shell variable.