# Bash script: Restore specific text in a file after some file editing

Tags: linux, bash, append

This question is linked with what I asked in [Bash script: Appending text at the last character of specific line of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5890052/703810).

After appending a variable at the end of a (file's) line that contains the unique string `MYVERSION`, I now want to restore the initial contents of this line.

I managed to store the initial contents of the line in a variable called `"OLD_MY_VERSION"` but when I am trying to restore the line with sed

> -i "/^MYVERSION=/ c\$$OLD_MY_VERSION myfile.txt

I am getting `"$MYVERSION=0.1"` instead of `"MYVERSION=0.1"` (without the quotes of course).

Any idea on how to remove the extra character ($)? If I don't put the extra $, I am not getting the contents of the `"OLD_MY_VERSION"` variable in the replacement but just the`"$OLD_MY_VERSION"` string.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try this:

```
sed -i "s/^MYVERSION=.*$/$OLD_MY_VERSION/" myfile.txt
```

This will substitute (`s`) the whole line beginning with `MYVERSION` with the content of `$OLD_MY_VERSION`.

You could also use the `c` command but you don't need the `\$` that you have in your command:

```
sed -i "/^MYVERSION/ c$OLD_MY_VERSION" myfile.txt
```