# Find unique string within a file, up a line and append?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

Can someone please help me with this scenario? I'm looking for a SED or AWK command that I can use to find a unique string within a config file (Linux), go up a line and append a string to the end of that line?

For example:

**config file:**

> define hostgroup{
>           hostgroup_name  http-urls ; The name of the hostgroup
>           alias           HTTP URLs ; Long name of the group
>           members         domain1.com, domain2.com, domain3.com,
>       #MyUniqueString
>           }

In the above example, I'd like to use SED or AWK to find **#MyUniqeString**, go up a line that starts with **members** and append **"domain4.com"** at the end of the line.

I found this question below but I need to search the text file first for the string, and go one line above.

[Bash script: Appending text at the last character of specific line of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890052/bash-script-appending-text-at-the-last-character-of-specific-line-of-a-file)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one-liner:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0}/#MyUniqueString/{a[NR-1]=a[NR-1]"domain4.com"}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)print a[i]}' configFile
```

test

```
kent$  cat test.txt 
define hostgroup{
hostgroup_name http-urls ; The name of the hostgroup
alias HTTP URLs ; Long name of the group
members domain1.com, domain2.com, domain3.com,
#MyUniqueString
}

kent$  awk '{a[NR]=$0}/#MyUniqueString/{a[NR-1]=a[NR-1]"domain4.com"}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)print a[i]}' test.txt 
define hostgroup{
hostgroup_name http-urls ; The name of the hostgroup
alias HTTP URLs ; Long name of the group
members domain1.com, domain2.com, domain3.com,domain4.com
#MyUniqueString
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this - I tried some of the others and this one best fits the question and works as you've illustrated.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this effectively with [`ed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html):

```
ed yourfile <<-'EOF'
    /#MyUniqueString/ # Find the matching line
    - # Go up a line
    a # Append text
    domain4.com
    . # Stop appending
    .-1,.j # Join the line above with the appended line
    w # Write the line
EOF
```

Comment: Oh, it works. The comments are for your benefit, not for pasting.

Answer (score 2):

### Comparission of three different solutions

#### Smaller, using `sed`:

```
sed -e ':a;N;/\n#MyUniqueString/{s/\n/ domain4.com\n/};H;s/\n.*$//;p;g;s/^.*\n//;ta;' config.file
```

This could be run as:

```
sed -e '
   :a;
    N;
    /\n#MyUniqueString/{
        s/\n/ domain4.com\n/
    };
    H;
    s/\n.*$//;
    p;
    g;
    s/^.*\n//;
    ta;
   ' config.file
```

*profiling:*

```
time sed ':a;N;/\n#MyUniqueString/{s/\n/ domain4.com\n/};H;
                      s/\n.*$//;p;g;s/^.*\n//;ta;' config.file 
define hostgroup{
hostgroup_name http-urls ; The name of the hostgroup
alias HTTP URLs ; Long name of the group
members domain1.com, domain2.com, domain3.com, domain4.com
#MyUniqueString
}



real    0m0.010s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.008s
```

#### Why not **pure bash** ?

As there is **no fork**, this could be very quick (if from `bash` and for not too long *config files*):

```
readarray configFile < ./config.file
for ((i=${#configFile};i--;));do
    [[ "${configFile[i]}" =~ "#MyUniqueString" ]] && break
  done
configFile[i-1]+=" domain4.com"
printf "%s\n" "${configFile[@]//$'\n'/}"
```

profiling run by:

```
time {
    readarray configFile < ./config.file
    for ((i=${#configFile};i--;));do
        [[ "${configFile[i]}" =~ "#MyUniqueString" ]] && break
      done
    configFile[i-1]+=" domain4.com"
    printf "%s\n" "${configFile[@]//$'\n'/}"
}
```

Will give:

```
define hostgroup{
hostgroup_name http-urls ; The name of the hostgroup
alias HTTP URLs ; Long name of the group
members domain1.com, domain2.com, domain3.com, domain4.com
#MyUniqueString
}

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

#### Test with `awk`

```
time awk '{a[NR]=$0}/#MyUniqueString/{a[NR-1]=a[NR-1]" domain4.com"}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)print a[i]}' config.file 
define hostgroup{
hostgroup_name http-urls ; The name of the hostgroup
alias HTTP URLs ; Long name of the group
members domain1.com, domain2.com, domain3.com, domain4.com
#MyUniqueString
}

real    0m0.009s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Comment: What's your environment? (I'm running *GNU sed version 4.2.1* on *Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.5*)

Answer (score 2):

here's another sed solution using backreferences:

```
sed '{N; N; s/\(.*\)\n\(#MyUniqueString\)/\1domain4.com\n\2/g}' config.file
```

Comment: that's odd... it works for your sample data.  oh well, as long as you got the result you wanted somehow.

Answer (score 1):

This awk solution only requires the previous line is remembered

```
awk '
    /#MyUniqueString/ {prev = prev "domain4.com"} 
    NR > 1 {print prev}
    {prev=$0}
    END {print prev}
'
```