# Find a line in a file, parse content between > and <, then add a line three lines after or before

Tags: bash, awk, sed, gawk

I need to edit a kml file with several thousand stanzas like the one below.  I can wrap my head around the logic but the actual implementation is beyond me.

Procedurally I need to:

1. Find the line that contains Sub_Name
2. Parse that line for the content between > and <
3. Add that content 4 lines before I found the line (or tac the file)
4. wash rinse repeat

I feel like I should be able to do this with a bash script and some moderately thorough sed and awk commands but the minute I start nesting everything craters.

```
  <Placemark>
 <name>THIS LINE NEEDS TO BE ADDED FROM THE Sub_Name LINE</name>
    <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#gmaps">
            <SimpleData name="EntID">1274433</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="Sub_Name">HYDE PARK</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="ORIG_FID">39</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="Scode">S5435</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="Shape_Leng">1653.15682579000</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="Shape_Area">13612381.56865700000</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
  <MultiGeometry><Polygon><altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode><coordinates>-97.7740412096895,30.4376501989282</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
```

This is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13958903/find-unique-string-within-a-file-up-a-line-and-append) question but I've been parsing it for an hour and can't make it fit my scenario.

Thanks for any suggestions and guidance you might have.

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far? Please take a look at the [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) session on the  [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Well, in the four hours I've been working on this the most relevant solution was the one I linked at the bottom of the question.  I've also read extensively through the man pages for sed, awk, bash and ed.  I've also gone through half a dozen in-depth how-to articles.  Out of curiosity which part of my question needs polishing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way is just to do it in 2 passes:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    if ( /Sub_Name/ ) {
        gsub(/[[:space:]]*<[^<>]+>/,"")
        names[NR-4] = ORS "<name>" $0 "</name>"
    }
    next
}
{ print $0 names[FNR] }

$ awk -f tst.awk file file
  <Placemark>
<name>HYDE PARK</name>
    <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#gmaps">
            <SimpleData name="EntID">1274433</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="Sub_Name">HYDE PARK</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="ORIG_FID">39</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="Scode">S5435</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="Shape_Leng">1653.15682579000</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="Shape_Area">13612381.56865700000</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
  <MultiGeometry><Polygon><altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode><coordinates>-97.7740412096895,30.4376501989282</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
```

The above was produced from this input file:

```
$ cat file
  <Placemark>
    <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#gmaps">
            <SimpleData name="EntID">1274433</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="Sub_Name">HYDE PARK</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="ORIG_FID">39</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="Scode">S5435</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="Shape_Leng">1653.15682579000</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="Shape_Area">13612381.56865700000</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
  <MultiGeometry><Polygon><altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode><coordinates>-97.7740412096895,30.4376501989282</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
```

The slightly harder way would involve keeping a rolling buffer of 4 lines and always print the 4th-last line read but that's only necessary if your input is coming from a pipe or your file is so huge you can't afford the time to parse it twice or memory to store all the "name" lines in an array.

The usual caveats about the dangerous of trying to parse HTML without an HTML parser apply...

Comment: Thanks Ed!  That was exactly the quick and dirty I was looking for.  My output was slightly different (put the new content next to the placemark tag) but I cleaned it up with vi and am done.  I probably have a typo somewhere.  Thanks a ton for the help.  I didn't think about it from this angle.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ cat xml_file
 <Placemark>
    <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#gmaps">
            <SimpleData name="EntID">1274433</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="Sub_Name">HYDE PARK</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="ORIG_FID">39</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="Scode">S5435</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="Shape_Leng">1653.15682579000</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="Shape_Area">13612381.56865700000</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
  <MultiGeometry><Polygon><altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode><coordinates>-97.7740412096895,30.4376501989282</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
   </Placemark>
```

If you *wanted* to parse that XML and use [xpath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) to find the value of a nested sub node and add another node, you might do something along these lines (Ruby as example):

```
$ ruby -r nokogiri -e 'doc=Nokogiri::XML($<.read) # {|opt| opt.strict.noblanks }   
    t1=doc.at_css "Placemark"
    t2 = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new "name", doc
    t2.parent=t1
    t2.content=doc.xpath("//SimpleData[@name=\"Sub_Name\"]").text
    puts doc
' xml_file
```

Prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Placemark>
    <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#gmaps">
            <SimpleData name="EntID">1274433</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="Sub_Name">HYDE PARK</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="ORIG_FID">39</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="Scode">S5435</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="Shape_Leng">1653.15682579000</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="Shape_Area">13612381.56865700000</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
  <MultiGeometry><Polygon><altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode><coordinates>-97.7740412096895,30.4376501989282</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></MultiGeometry>
   <name>HYDE PARK</name></Placemark>
```

(Note that the inserted node `<name>HYDE PARK</name>` is at the end of the `<Placemark>` node since no XML order was specified by a schema.)

Any other scripting language with a XML parser will be similar (Ruby, Python, Perl, jq, etc.)